# Java override conflict - same name with different return type

Tags: java, conflict, name-collision

I tried to create a class that extended *File* class (*`java.io.File`*) and implement *TreeNode* interface like below:

```
public class mTreeNode extends File implements TreeNode{}
```

and tried to implement *TreeNode* methods but a conflict occurred.

`public String getParent(){}` on *File* class has conflict with `public TreeNode getParent()` on *TreeNode* interface on return type.

How can we solve it ? (for example why can't use Object class for return type !)

Finally I decided use a file object on my class.

Comment: `How can we solve it ?` Make the return types match.

Comment: What version of Java?  What is the code for TreeNode?

Comment: Google on [inheritance vs composition](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=inheritance+vs+composition)

Comment: Same method with different return type is not valid in Java

Comment: It is actually `getParent()` not `getPattern()`, not that it matters much in the context of a question.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani That's not quite correct. Return types can be covariant with the containing class type. See the JLS.

Comment: @EJP Please give some of the link for the reference if you have

Comment: @TofuBeer Neither the version of Java nor the implementation of TreeNode have anything to do with it.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani [Covariant Return Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#d5e11321), but I really think you could have found that for yourself.

Comment: This is a duplicate of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672742/so-in-java-you-cant-have-duplicate-method-names-with-different-return-and-param

Answer (score 2):

Since `TreeNode` is an interface, you are required to implement that method with its *exact* signature.  It's a contract between the class that implements it and the outside world that is enforced by the compiler.

You can read more about it [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

Answer (score 1):

Classes that implement interfaces may declare [covariant return types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type). So the return types in classes that implement interfaces must either match the interface or be a sub-class of the interface.

e.g.

```
class Foo {
    public String toString() {
        return "foo";
    }
}

interface Interface {
    Foo getFoo();    
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public String toString() {
        return "bar";
    }
}

class Concrete implements Interface {
    public Bar getFoo() {  // <============= Covariant return type
        return new Bar();
    }
}

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Concrete().getFoo());
    }
}
```

The class will print `bar`.